# Kaminari: not paginating in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

Pagination is not working in production (heroku).
In development, it works perfectly fine, using:

`<%= link_to_next_page(@posts_filtered, 'Next Page', :remote => true %>`

However, in production, it is stuck with the "Loading next page ...".
When opening manually the link which "Loading next page ..." is pointing at, I get a white page with an error in the console:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)`

I should also mention that I have a SSL certificate installed (which is the main difference I see between production and development).

Anyone ever encountered this issue ?